# Kendo query filter using Odata v4 fails for certain filter options

Tags: c#, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

I am using a kendo grid with server filtering turned on and the grid calls a datasource which is a web api controller that accepts a custom Model binder (by implementing IModelBinder), which does custom sorting and paging on Odata result. Now I am seeing issues when certain filter options are used.

Please note that i have already fixed the issue with 'substringof', as web services using odata v4 no longer acknowledge the substringof function which is explained [here](http://www.tagwith.com/question_1001301_odata-v4-working-with-kendoui-grid-contains-filter). I tried specifying odata-v4 in the grid config but that did not work either. So ended up converting the filters to replace 'substringof' to 'contains' in the custom model binder

The below Url's work requests work and return data

http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+eq+11)
http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+gt+11)
http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+lt+11)

The below Url's do not work requests work and return an exception. This is Greater than or Equal to, Less that or Equal To and Not Equal to filters.

http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+ge+11)
http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+le+11)
http://localhost:63455/api/data/gethistory?$top=5&$filter=(Id+eq+1+and+PaymentId+ne+11)

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Expected
>   RightParenthesis","ExceptionType":"Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParserException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.Expect(FilterTokenType
>   tokenType)\r\n   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.ParseNestedExpression()\r\n
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.PrimaryExpression()\r\n
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.ComparisonExpression()\r\n
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.AndExpression()\r\n
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.OrExpression()\r\n
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.Expression()\r\n 
>   at Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParser.Parse()\r\n
>   at Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.FilterDescriptorFactory.Create(String
>   input)\r\n   at
>   RequestModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext
>   actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)